# Camera works fine in sandboxie, but not in regular system - fold sandboxie changes back to system?

Tags: windows-7, sandboxie

We're using a video chat program that runs fine in sandboxie, but will not run in the normal environment.  How do we get the normally functioning sandboxie folded back into the system?

Briefly:

In win7 home premium machine emachine E732, opened program and went to video settings.. Kaboom.

The error message follows:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: BEX
  Application Name: Camfrog Video Chat 6.5.300.exe
  Application Version: 6.5.300.4793
  Application Timestamp: 51dd3a45
  Fault Module Name: MSVCR90.dll
  Fault Module Version: 9.0.30729.4940
  Fault Module Timestamp: 4ca2ef57
  Exception Offset: 00037256
  Exception Code: c0000417
  Exception Data: 00000000
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 9a05
  Additional Information 2: 9a05443bd049b4e1d023fca8c6ecd575
  Additional Information 3: 9676
  Additional Information 4: 967665049b9d98f0aa9531e1e790c038
Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```